# Building Logical queries using Sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot-solr

I have a User and Skill model, having (has_many association) where indexing is done using sunspot.
Now the requirement is to implement logical queries.

Example "skill1 AND skill2"
"skill1 OR skill2"
"skill1 AND skill2 OR skill3"

And Sunspot is using the dismax request handler where minimum_match field is used to implement OR queries.

Now the problem is when we need to combine AND and OR operators together.
How to implement the same.

Regards,
Karan